# HTML, JS - Contact form checkboxes text display problem

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have 4 check boxes in my contact form. They have implemented functionality of radio buttons, so when you click on other checkbox the first checkbox gets unchecked.

My problem is when you click on checkbox 1, it displays text which is right. But when you click on checkbox number 2 or 3 or 4 the text should disappear and it does not.

Maybe I need to connect my JS codes into one function but I am newbie in JS so maybe you could help me with this.

Code is here

JS

```
function checkOnlyOne(b){

var x = document.getElementsByClassName('daychecks');
var i;

for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
if(x[i].value != b) x[i].checked = false;
}

$(function () {

var submityesClicked;

//catch the click to buttons
$('#submityes').click(function () {
    submityesClicked = true;
});
$('#submitno').click(function () {
    submityesClicked = false;
});

$('#webform').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();//prevent the default action

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        /*url: "process.php", //process to mail
         data: $('form.contact').serialize(),*/
        success: function (msg) {
            window.location.replace(submityesClicked ? "/submit_resolved_yes.php" : "/submit_resolved_no.php");
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
});
});

function myFunction() {
var checkBox = document.getElementById("document1");
var text = document.getElementById("text");
if (checkBox.checked == true){
text.style.display = "block";
} else {
 text.style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById("myFunction").checked = false;
}
}
```

HTML code

```
 <form name="cf2"  id="formularos" method="post" action="test.php">
                            <div class="checkbox-group required">
                            <p class="center">Vyberte školenie</p>
                            <label  class="container riadok"><p for="document1" class="dolava">§20 Poučená osoba</p>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="daychecks"  name="document[]" value="20" id="document1" onclick="checkOnlyOne(this.value); myFunction()" />
                            <span class="checkmark"></span>
                            
                            </label>
                            <label class="container riadok"><p for="document" class="dolava">Aktualizácia: §21 AŽ §24</p>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="daychecks"  name="document[]" value="21-24" id="document2" onclick="checkOnlyOne(this.value);" >
                            <span class="checkmark"></span>
                            </label>
                            <label class="container riadok"><p for="document" class="dolava">§21 AŽ §23 pre EZ</p>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="daychecks"  name="document[]" value="21-23" id="document3" onclick="checkOnlyOne(this.value);" >
                            <span class="checkmark"></span>
                            </label>
                            <label class="container riadok"><p for="document" class="dolava">§24 Revízny technik</p>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="daychecks" name="document[]" value="24" id="document4" onclick="checkOnlyOne(this.value);" >
                            <span class="checkmark"></span>
                            </label>
                            
                            
            <p id="text" style="display:none">ZÁVÄZNÁ PRIHLÁŠKA <br>Na "Kurz o POUČENEJ OSOBE" <br>pre držiteľov platných „Osvedčení“ podľa vyhl. MPSVaR SR č. 508/09 Z. z , § 20, podľa § 16 odst. 4 a 7 zákona č. 124/2006 Z. z., o BOZP a zmene a doplnení niektorých zákonov v znení neskorších predpisov , ktorými sa dopĺňa zákon č. 355/2007 Z. z., o podpore verejného zdravia, najmä zák. č. 470/2011 Z. z. s vyznačením účasti na origináli „ Osvedčenia“.</p>
           
                            </div>
                            <p class="center">Vyplňte osobné údaje</p>
                            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Meno" required="required">
                            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required="required">
                            <input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefónne číslo" pattern="[0-9]+"  title="Zadajte iba čísla." required="required">
                            
<input type="hidden" name="send" value="1" />
 <button type="submit" value="SEND"  id="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> ODOSLAŤ PRIHLÁŠKU</button>

</form>
```

URL of the page is here
[URL DEMO](https://test-m.3way.sk/prihlaska.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few improvements needed in your `code` which i have done and is working as expected now.

You need to call `myFunction` text display on each `checkbox` - In that function you can just `this` which refer to the element clicked and and in the function just check if the input is `checked` and the `id` of the element is `document1` this way you do not need to write code each input or multiple texts you have.

Also, you do no need to check the if condition by adding `true` to it since `if (e.checked)` means this will `truthy` - (true) if you do no need define anything as well as you do no need to checked false as well. Since as soon as the boxes changes the it will `unchecked` by `default`

**Edit:** Since you wanted to display `different` text on different `checkbox` checked. I have added that functionality as well.

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
function checkOnlyOne(b) {

  var x = document.getElementsByClassName('daychecks');
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i].value != b) x[i].checked = false;
  }
}

$(function() {

  var submityesClicked;

  //catch the click to buttons
  $('#submityes').click(function() {
    submityesClicked = true;
  });
  $('#submitno').click(function() {
    submityesClicked = false;
  });

  $('#webform').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent the default action

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      /*url: "process.php", //process to mail
       data: $('form.contact').serialize(),*/
      success: function(msg) {
        window.location.replace(submityesClicked ? "/submit_resolved_yes.php" : "/submit_resolved_no.php");
      },
      error: function() {
        alert("error");
      }
    });
  });
});

function myFunction(e) {
  var text = document.getElementById("text"); //1
  var text2 = document.getElementById("text2"); //2
  var text3 = document.getElementById("text3"); //3
  var text4 = document.getElementById("text4"); //4
  e.checked && e.getAttribute('id') == 'document1' ? text.style.display = "block" : text.style.display = "none";
  e.checked && e.getAttribute('id') == 'document2' ? text2.style.display = "block" : text2.style.display = "none";
  e.checked && e.getAttribute('id') == 'document3' ? text3.style.display = "block" : text3.style.display = "none";
  e.checked && e.getAttribute('id') == 'document4' ? text4.style.display = "block" : text4.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="cf2" id="formularos" method="post" action="test.php">
  <div class="checkbox-group required">
    <p class="center">Vyberte školenie</p>
    <label class="container riadok">
      <p for="document1" class="dolava">§20 Poučená osoba</p>
      <input type="checkbox" class="daychecks" name="document[]" value="20" id="document1" onclick="checkOnlyOne(this.value); myFunction(this)" />
      <span class="checkmark"></span>

    </label>
    <label class="container riadok">
      <p for="document" class="dolava">Aktualizácia: §21 AŽ §24</p>
      <input type="checkbox" class="daychecks" name="document[]" value="21-24" id="document2" onclick="checkOnlyOne(this.value); myFunction(this)">
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    <label class="container riadok">
      <p for="document" class="dolava">§21 AŽ §23 pre EZ</p>
      <input type="checkbox" class="daychecks" name="document[]" value="21-23" id="document3" onclick="checkOnlyOne(this.value); myFunction(this)">
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    <label class="container riadok">
      <p for="document" class="dolava">§24 Revízny technik</p>
      <input type="checkbox" class="daychecks" name="document[]" value="24" id="document4" onclick="checkOnlyOne(this.value); myFunction(this)">
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>


    <p id="text" style="display:none">ZÁVÄZNÁ PRIHLÁŠKA <br>Na "Kurz o POUČENEJ OSOBE" <br>pre držiteľov platných „Osvedčení“ podľa vyhl. MPSVaR SR č. 508/09 Z. z , § 20, podľa § 16 odst. 4 a 7 zákona č. 124/2006 Z. z., o BOZP a zmene a doplnení niektorých zákonov v znení neskorších predpisov
      , ktorými sa dopĺňa zákon č. 355/2007 Z. z., o podpore verejného zdravia, najmä zák. č. 470/2011 Z. z. s vyznačením účasti na origináli „ Osvedčenia“.</p>

    <p id="text2" style="display:none">Text 2 <br>Test 2</p>

    <p id="text3" style="display:none">Text 3 <br>Test 3</p>
    <p id="text4" style="display:none">Text 4 <br>Test 4</p>


  </div>
  <p class="center">Vyplňte osobné údaje</p>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Meno" required="required">
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required="required">
  <input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefónne číslo" pattern="[0-9]+" title="Zadajte iba čísla." required="required">

  <input type="hidden" name="send" value="1" />
  <button type="submit" value="SEND" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> ODOSLAŤ PRIHLÁŠKU</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, it works.
Dont you know how could I edit js functio to display even text2 for document2 checkbox for example?

Comment: I have tried this but it did not work
`var checkBox = document.getElementById("document1");
  var checkBox2 = document.getElementById("document2");
  var text = document.getElementById("text");
  var text2 = document.getElementById("text2");`

Comment: @LuboMasura Yeah sure. let me check how that can be added :)

Comment: If its possible I need 4 of the documents and text. Now I have only one. Thank you very much !!!

Comment: @LuboMasura Check my answer - all working for you. Showing different text on different checkbox checked

Comment: It does not works for me, damn :/ Idk why it looks legit.

Comment: @LuboMasura umm weird - in my answer its all working perfectly as you wanted. Have you added the code to your website so that i can check what going on ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221372/discussion-between-lubo-masura-and-alwayshelping).

Answer (score 1):

Im blind and I did not input call to a function into other checkboxes.
Fixed by adding function to every checkbox.

```
 <label  class="container riadok"><p for="document1" class="dolava">§20 
 Poučená osoba</p>
 <input type="checkbox" class="daychecks"  name="document[]" value="20" 
 id="document1" onclick="checkOnlyOne(this.value); myFunction()" />
 <span class="checkmark"></span>
 </label>
<label class="container riadok"><p for="document" 
class="dolava">Aktualizácia: §21 AŽ §24</p>
<input type="checkbox" class="daychecks"  name="document[]" value="21-24" 
id="document2" onclick="checkOnlyOne(this.value); myFunction()" >
<span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container riadok"><p for="document" class="dolava">§21 AŽ §23 
pre EZ</p>
<input type="checkbox" class="daychecks"  name="document[]" value="21-23" 
id="document3" onclick="checkOnlyOne(this.value); myFunction()" >
<span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container riadok"><p for="document" class="dolava">§24 Revízny 
technik</p>
<input type="checkbox" class="daychecks" name="document[]" value="24" 
id="document4" onclick="checkOnlyOne(this.value); myFunction()" >
<span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```